# Convert xPath to jQuery Selector

Tags: jquery, xpath, jquery-selectors

How do I convert the following xPath into a jQuery 1.10 selector?

```
/html/body/div[4]/div[2]/div/div/div/ul/li[4]
```

I'd like to use the result to do something like this:

```
jQuery('selector').hide();
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, it's a question of identifying the syntactical differences:

- XPath uses `/` as a parent/child delimiter, while CSS/jQuery selectors use `>`.
- XPath uses one-indexed square brackets to denote index, whereas jQuery uses the `:nth-child()` pseudo-selector

So:

```
let xpath = '/html/body/div[4]/div[2]/div/div/div/ul/li[4]';
let jq_sel = xpath
    .substr(1) //discard first slash
    .replace(/\//g, ' > ')
    .replace(/\[(\d+)\]/g, ($0, i) => ':nth-child('+i+')');
```

Comment: This worked fine except for dealing with the `nth-child` selectors. I can't seem to get this to work in JQuery 3+. Maybe they've changed something. Otherwise works well enough so long as you don't have to get to a specific child. I corrected this with a minor change based upon the answer by @razielx4crazy below.

Comment: it seems 'nth-child' matches any tag, xpath div[x] will match the xth div (not other tags)

Answer (score 3):

This would be something like this:

```
$('html body div:eq(4) div:eq(2) div div div ul li:eq(4)')
```

Im not sure about divs, maybe it could be like this another one:

```
$('html body div:eq(4) div:eq(2) div:first div:first div:first ul li:eq(4)')
```