# How to isolate a selector usable in document.querySelector, from Xpath?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, xpath

There is an element I really want to select with `document.querySelector`. The problem is that the makers of the site I work on, didn't give any identifier to this element.

It's just one of about 600 spans in the webpage with a huge DOM and I've no desire (nor the spare time) to manually count all spans in the DOM to know what item reference `span[n] // n == number` to use as it would be a nightmare and there must be some other better way, at least to get the item reference via devtool.

### Selection ways I tried so far

I tried to copy "Css path" or "Css selector" and put either inside my code:

```
let myEl = document.querySelector('CSS-PATH-FROM-DEVTOOL');
myEl.click();

let myEl = document.querySelector('CSS-SELECTOR-FROM-DEVTOOL');
myEl.click();
```

Yet the element wasn't selected in both cases and no click happened.

Selecting via `textDocument` isn't good because there are many spans with the same `textDocument`.

### Utilizing Xpath for selection

I understand that in such a "special" case when an element has no IDs, classes, to make it unique and is just one tag of many of the same kind, and neither CSS path or CSS selector helps targeting, then I could use Xpath.

Well, when I copy the Xpath I get:

```
*[@id="js_30"]/div/ul/li[4]/a/span/span
```

### My question

How could this be used to select the element with `document.querySelector`?

As I'm new to JS, I tried the following which didn't help, the element won't be clicked:

```
let myEl = document.querySelector(' *[@id="js_30"]/div/ul/li[4]/a/span/span ');
MyEl.click();
```

Is there a way to target to select only that particular element, directly?

Comment: You can of course not feed your XPath into querySelector - that method is for CSS selectors only. So you will have to “translate” your XPath to a CSS selector. The `/` would become `>`, and `[x]` can be replaced with `:nth-child()` ... so give that a try.

Comment: Post a [mcve] that includes the HTML.

Comment: CBore, I tried this `document.querySelector(' *[@id="js_en"] > div > ul > li:nth-child(4) > a > span > span ')` but I get "is not a valid selector" error.

Comment: No, adding images doesn't help.  Create a real **[mcve]**, including actual HTML, as text, formatted as code, in your question.  Furthermore, scraping FB is probably against their terms of service.  Voting to close...

Comment: @user8551674: Change `*[@id="js_en"]` to `#js_en`.

Comment: @kjhughes: The XPath alone is enough to identify the element without the need for an HTML sample. And ToS violations are not a reason to close a question.

Comment: @BoltClock: It's prefered to include markup in the question when asking about selecting nodes because often whether a selector is over- or underspecified cannot otherwise be determined.  ...  ToS violation: Surprised to hear you say that; I know I'm not comfortable helping someone violate ToS of any site.

Comment: @kjhughes: The XPath is from the browser developer tools and is guaranteed to be unique to each element for the given page. Of course, any variations would still have to be accounted for - but the sample HTML alone will not do that, unless all the possible variations are listed.

Comment: @BoltClock: You're assuming that OP literally only needs to know the CSS selector for a given XPath.  In my experience, without including markup, such questions are often incomplete, requiring further rounds of updates and/or being less useful to future readers.  However, I defer to your judgement as this should require no further time of yours or mine.  Update/delete my comments as you wish. (I do stand by my ToS position, though.)  Cheers.

Comment: Sadly, @BoltClock `document.querySelector(' #js_en > div > ul > li:nth-child(4) > a > span > span` ').click()` returns "Cannot read property of null".

Answer (score 3):

Based on [an answer by Utkanos](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22571004/), you can do this:

```
var elem,
    xpath = '*[@id="js_30"]/div/ul/li[4]/a/span/span',
    jq_sel = xpath
        .substr(14) // remove id part
        .replace(/\//g, ' > ')
        .replace(/\[(\d+)\]/g, function ($0, i) { return ':nth-child(' + i + ')'; });

// add id part: #js_30 > div > ul > li:nth-child(4) > a > span > span
jq_sel = '#js_30' + jq_sel;
 // query element
elem = document.querySelectorAll(jq_sel);
// simulate a mouse click
elem.click();

console.log("*");
console.log("xpath:", xpath);
console.log("jq_sel:", jq_sel);
console.log("elem:", elem);
```